# Is it a correct approach to mmap a entire large file for processing, and question on performace in MPI

Tags: python, parallel-processing, io, mpi, mmap

I'm trying to process a large JSON file (around 10GB) line by line using MPI in python. The approach I took was dividing the lines among all the available processes and let each process only deal with the lines that correspond to its rank number.

```py
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

with open(path, 'r') as f:

    for index, line in enumerate(f):
        if index % size == rank:
            #do some process with line
    comm.Barrier()
# do MPI reduction on results from all the processes
```

The code works fine but I wanna further improve the performance, so I tried to use mmap to read the file instead. I create a mmap object of the whole file in each process.

```py
with open(path, 'r') as f:

    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    for index, line in enumerate(iter(mm.readline, b'')):
        if index % size == rank:
            #do some process with line
    comm.Barrier()
    mm.close()
# do MPI reduction on results from all the processes
```

I ran the code on a remote HPC system with different resources, e.g. 1 node 1 task, 1 node 8 tasks and 2 nodes 8 tasks (with 4 tasks per node). The results have indeed improved in all cases compared to using standard I/O. The execution time is 20 seconds shorter on average.

I have two questions:

First, since I have limited knowledge in I/O, virtual memory, etc, I'm wondering if this is somewhat a 'correct' approach to process a large file? I learned that mmap uses virtual address space to map the file from disk. Does it mean that as long as the virtual address space could fit the whole file, there is no problem in doing so?

Second, the results of 2 nodes 8 tasks are generally quicker than 1 node 8 tasks. At first I thought it should be the other way around, since 1 node means less communication overhead between the processes. Now my guess is that in my program there isn't that much communication needed. Instead 2 nodes means separate I/O in each node, which leads to faster speed. Is my guess correct, or could there be some other reasons?

Comment: where is located your input file ? on an external NFS file server or a parallel filesystem ? each node has its own copy in its local storage ? Your code snippet does not show any kind of MPI communication, and each MPI task read the full file and "split" it into lines. Then each task process only a unique subset of lines. That means that as long as file I/O are scalable and line processing is faster than line reading, adding more nodes should improve performance.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I'm not entirely sure where my file is located, but as far as I understand, it's on an NFS file server. Basically, I log in to my account on the HPC system by ssh, then I made a symbolic link to the actual input files which are located in another folder. Can you elaborate on why adding more nodes would improve performance?

Comment: if the performance is limited by the time it takes to process a line, then more MPI tasks (regardless they are located on the same node or not) will reduce the elapsed time.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet In this case, with both 1 node and 2 nodes, the number of tasks are the same (8). I still don't quite get why 2 nodes are faster than 1 node?

Comment: oops, I misread the question. If the performance of your application is limited by the memory bandwidth (which is the most common case), then 2 nodes vs 1 node means twice the memory bandwidth, which can explain the performance gain (even if MPI inter node communications are slower than intra node ones).

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thanks for the answer! I'm not very familiar with the concept of memory bandwidth. Does it affect the speed of I/O? In this case, is memory bandwidth related more to line processing or line reading?